# How to write more than 1 strings to shared memory using shmop_write php?

Tags: php, string, shared-memory

I'm pretty new here and I need help.
Do you know how to write more than 1 strings to shared memory using shmop_write php?

this is my php syntax:

```
$key = 864;
$mode = 'c';
$permission = 0644;
$size = 1024;

$shmid = shmop_open($key, $mode, $permission, $size);

$string = "This is String 1";
$string2 = "String 2";

shmop_write($shmid, $string, 0);    
shmop_write($shmid, $string2, 0);

$size = shmop_size($shmid);
echo shmop_read($shmid, 0, $size);

shmop_delete($shmid);
shmop_close($shmid);
```

Expected Result (**Wanted result**) : **This is String 1String 2**

BUT, **The Result** of that syntax is : **String 2String 1**

and if I change `$string = "String 1"` from `$string = "This is String 1"`,
the result still : `String 2String 1` (like can't refresh the memory block)

Can you tell me how to get the wanted result? Thx.

Comment: `shmop_write($shmid, $string . $string2, 0);`?

Comment: Write them at different offsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared memory is not a stream, it's just a block of memory. The third argument to `shmop_read()` specifies where in the memory block the write should happen. If you write to the same offset, it just overwrites what was there before. If you want to write one thing after another, you need to specify a different offset:

```
shmop_write($shmid, $string, 0);
shmop_write($shmid, $string2, strlen($string));
```

If you want to write lots of things to the shared memory, update a variable to track the current position:

```
$offset = 0;
shmop_write($shmid, $string, $offset);
$offset += strlen($string);
shmop_write($shmid, $string2, $offset);
$offset += strlen($string2);
shmop_write($shmid, $string3, $offset);
$offset += strlen($string3);
shmop_write($shmid, $string4, $offset);
$offset += strlen($string4);
```

A good idea would be to implement this using a class, where `$offset` is a class property.

Comment: Thx Barmar, this is the answer that I search. Oh yeah, I want to ask you one more. Do you know how to clear data from shared memory? 

let say
$string = "String 1",
$string2 = "String 2",
$string3 = "String 3",

after I did from your answer,
the result is = "String 1String 2String 3";

but, if I change $string = "Str",
the result = "StrString 2String 3ing 3" -

But, the "ing 3" in last result is from previous experiment, so how to erase it? Thx..

Comment: Since you have to keep track of how much you've written, you should use that as the length argument to `shm_read()`.